# Using tkinter, how to solve the problem with second button in python which result from second button do not display properly

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a simple calculation system using tkinter. first the user need to enter the amount and there are 3 first row button and 2 second row button. After the user enter their value then click any first row button which contain value 4, 8 and 12. The amount that user enter will be multiply by the value contains in first button. Then the result from first button will be multiply by the second row button. Then final result will be displayed at the bottom. The problem is that in the second row button, i can't display the result properly and i try using if statement in second button functions but it not working. Anyone have any ideas that can help me solve it please share, thank you

Here the code for your references

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Calculation")
e = Entry(root, width = 35, borderwidth = 5)
e.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=3, padx = 10,pady=10)

res = Entry(root, width = 35, borderwidth = 5)
res.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx = 10, pady=10)

def multi_4(number):
    duration= int(e.get())*number
    global f_num1
    global current_number
    current_number = duration
    f_num1 = duration
    res.delete(END)
    res.insert(0,duration)
  
def multi_8(number):
    duration= int(e.get())*number
    global f_num2
    global current_number2
    current_number2 = duration
    f_num2 = duration
    res.delete(0,END)
    res.insert(0,duration)
    return duration

def multi_12(number):
    duration= int(e.get())*number
    global f_num3
    global current_number3
    current_number3 = duration
    f_num3 = duration
    res.delete(0,END)
    res.insert(0,duration)
    return duration

def multi_52(number):
    
    res.delete(0,END)
    res.insert(0, f_num1 * number)
    res.insert(0,f_num2 * number)
    res.insert(0, f_num3 * number)

def multi_12i(number, duration):
    total = duration * number
    res.delete(0,END)
    res.insert(0,total)

button_1 = Button(root, text="4 (2024)", padx =40, pady =20, command=lambda: multi_4(4))
button_2 = Button(root, text="8 (2028)", padx =40, pady =20, command=lambda: multi_8(8))
button_3 = Button(root, text="12 (2032)", padx =40, pady =20, command=lambda: multi_12(12))
button_4 = Button(root, text="52 Weeks", padx =40, pady =20, command=lambda: multi_52(52))
button_5 = Button(root, text="12 Months", padx =40, pady =20, command=lambda: multi_12i(12))


#put the button on the screen
button_1.grid(row = 1 , column=0)
button_2.grid(row = 1 , column=1)
button_3.grid(row = 1, column=2)

button_4.grid(row = 2, column=0)
button_5.grid(row = 2, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You may need to declare `duration` as global variable and remove `duration` argument from `multi_12i()` function.  Also referring `f_num1` to `f_num3` at the same time inside `multi_52()` will raise exception because if only one of the first row buttons is clicked, only one of the three variables will be created.

Comment: so for multi_52() , i try to do the if statement to do the calculation based on  3 input from 3 first row button. But it will show only one result which is result for button_1 not matter what button click from 3 first row. is there any possible way to correct it?

Comment: The three variables `f_num1` to `f_num3` are assigned the value of `duration` finally, so you can use `duration` inside `multi_52()` instead of the three variables.

Comment: Also `res.delete(END)` inside `multi_4()` should be `res.delete(0, END)` instead.

Comment: Okay i get it now, Thank you for your help, really appreciate it. Thanks !